# Resolve variable name for MongoRepository in Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongorepository

What is the correct method name for variable with `_` in MongoRepository.

**History.java**

```
@Document(collection = "spring-history")
public class History {
    private Long record_id;

    //getter - setter
}
```

**HistoryRepository.java**

```
public interface HistoryRepository extends MongoRepository<History, String>{
    List<History> findAllByRecordid(Long recordId);
}
```

I got the following exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property recordid found for type History! Did you mean 'record_id'?
```

I've tried following variable options but none of this working.

```
List<History> findAllByRecordId(Long recordId);
List<History> findAllByRecord_id(Long recordId);
List<History> findAllByRecord__id(Long recordId);
```

Comment: Try `@Field("record_id") private Long recordId;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says that there is `No property recordid found for type History!`.

This happens because your repository method written as `findAllByRecordid` is currently looking for a property `recordid` inside the `History` class.

What you have to do is to chang your `History` class accordingly; for example, you can change

```
private Long record_id;
```

to

```
private Long recordid;
```

However, since I suppose that `record_id` is a composed name variable, you should use the camel case convention and name it `recordId`.

Following the camel case convention, you have to also change the repository method to  `List<History> findByRecordId(Long recordId);`

In this case, you have also to annotate the `recordId` with the `@Field` annotation in order to map the `recordId` property to the actual key in the MongoDB BSON document. for further details/information, you can give a look at [Mapping annotation overview](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-annotations)

Comment: As you know mongodb process JSONDocument so we used standards of JSON in key name. Also we've thousands of record inserted in mongodb with `record_id` so can't change it now. I've also tried `@JsonProperty("record_id") private Long recordId;` but its not working

Comment: You have to use the `@Field` annotation on the property to actually map it to the JSON key name.

Answer (score 0):

change your variable declaration from

```
private Long record_id;
```

to

```
private Long recordId;
```

and use this:

```
List<History> findByRecordId(Long recordId);
```

Comment: As you know mongodb process JSONDocument so we used standards of JSON in key name. Also we've thousands of record inserted in mongodb with `record_id` so can't change it now. I've also tried `@JsonProperty("record_id") private Long recordId;` but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Field("record_id") 
private Long recordId;
```